# Doubt on a fake proof of $e^{i\pi}=-1$.

Tags: solution-verification, fake-proofs

This might be a pretty elementary question, but I just want to ensure that my doubts are correct. I was checking my social media today and I accidentally saw one "simple" proof of Euler's Identity. Here is the link: [Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/ArtOfMathematics/posts/615244265563618). It basically uses integration to show that $\pi = 2i\ln(-1)$.
[image: The "proof"]
**I highly doubt that this is a valid proof because, in my understanding, you can't show that $\ln(-1)$ or $\ln(i)$ exists without Euler's Equation. Therefore, I see this as a pretty bad pseudo proof. Is my doubt correct?**

---

Here is another weird stuff from the author of the pseudo proof. This so-called "definition" is absolute nonsense for me because you need $e$ to define $\ln$.
[image]

Comment: This proof is simply absurd.

Comment: @KaboMurphy Yes I am trying to illustrate the same thing. This proof actually got pretty viral on social media.

Comment: Yeah I mean there are about a million identical ways to formulate this identity, and no matter what you are sweeping something else under the rug unless you get a bit messy with the careful details. I agree its pretty absurd to casually throw around things like $\ln(i)$ while presuming to not know Euler's identity.

Comment: @ElliotG Agreed.

Comment: I agree with you and the others, these are not proof, just reformulations (and poorly done).

Comment: My favorite "bad proof" of this is to just use calculus to show that the derivative of $e^{-ix}(\cos x+i\sin x)$ is $0$, and then note that $x=0$ shows $e^{-ix}(\cos x+i\sin x)=1$ for all $x$. You might as well make it a slick bad proof!

Comment: @ElliotG interesting

Comment: @ElliotG why is that a "bad proof"?

Comment: I just presume that you would use Euler's identity somewhere along the way when you were constructing complex differentiation... or something.

Comment: You know that you're in for a wild ride when the author types a sentence $in\ the\ Latex\ variable\ font.$

Comment: @ElliotG as long as you have shown that $e^x, \cos(x), \sin(x)$ are complex-differentiable functions, then you're not using Euler's identity at any point along the proof

Comment: Ok sure I agree now. I suppose you can do that pretty straight-forwardly by defining with series.

Comment: If we really wanted to make the facebook proof work, we could define the $\ln$ as an inverse to $e^x$ and then note that $\ln(AB) = \ln(A) + \ln(B)$ must hold over the domain of this newly defined $\ln$.  However, we would then need to somehow establish (without Euler's formula) that $1 \pm i$ and $\pm i$ lie within the domain of this inverse.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That is actually a quite interesting idea.